# Was I not welcoming enough?

Tags: discussion, welcoming

We had funny situation this day ... it's regarding this question 
[SQL: Why doesn't my trigger work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360268/sql-why-doesnt-my-trigger-work?noredirect=1#comment89693946_51360268)

Fully unclear question, more not needed information and less needed ones ... you can see what person is doing wrong, but you can't fix it unless more information is provided

Anyway, I asked her to join chat room, so I can explain her what is she doing wrong ... but before she join I did said that a question she asked *"is dumb"* which is true ... question is dumb and 95% of the times first questions asked by new members are dumb (which I also said), including mine (heck, most of my questions are dumb).

I started explaining what she was doing wrong and how to fix it and all of a sudden she vanish from chat room ...

Now, beside my personal opinion, I tried to help her and she declined my help ...

So does this situation goes to *"SO is not welcoming enough"*? Do I deserve a *"time-out"* from SO for thinking and saying some question is *"dumb"*, or just for saying it?

Comment: Not sure.  'dumb' may well be seen as rude, but then again, it was a tech. exchange in a private chat so.... I woud just move on and not worry about it.  Not much you can do now, anyway.

Comment: _"question is stupid as hell"_ _"
true true , aint saying she is stupid :D just saying question is bad :)"_ Not the most welcoming thing in the world, but, you are judging the question and not the OP so imo it seems fine

Comment: I'm pretty sure you wouldn't feel great if we started to say in comments that we believe this question is dumb.

Comment: Does stating the question as dumb improve your ability to provide help in anyway?

Comment: Also, note that the OP is low-rep.  I have a policy of not commenting on such questions at all.   If a  Q. from a low rep user is bad, I down/close vote it only because commenting causes pain too often;(

Comment: It's hard to call a question dumb without some of that blowing back onto the OP.  So while you weren't calling the OP dumb directly, it's heavily implied.

Comment: @yivi That was my honest opinion. I wasn't trying to illustrate. I just didn't need the feel to hold back since he clearly thinks calling his questions dumb is OK.

Comment: @user2285236 That something is an "honest opinion" doesn't exempt you from trying to be nice. And "they started it" is not a great strategy to go around. We want to help other users to do better, not respond to rudeness with rudeness.

Comment: Your question is a nice example for how different people are that interact on SO. What is nice to a person with cultural background $A is rude to a person with cultural background $B. It would help if everybody who is judging nice vs. rude would consider this.

Comment: @LutzHorn: In which culture is saying "Your work is stupid as hell" nice to someone you don't know? Or calling someone "poor little lady"?

Comment: @yivi I honestly don't care what strategy is best to go around. He can call someone's question dumb. When that someone is offended, he can call her "poor little lady". Then it is also OK to come here and ask "there was nothing wrong with it, right"? But yeah, I am the one who has to be nice here.

Comment: @BDL Not in mine. But maybe in Serbia?

Comment: @user2285236 The rules do not only apply to the OP.

Comment: @George Most would consider criticism directed at something to also be directed at the creator of that thing. Calling a question dumb isn't that different from calling the author dumb (for most).

Comment: @Dukeling How can something be insulted? Only a person can.

Comment: @LutzHorn "something" can be insulted, it might not be able to react / understand the insult but it can surely be insulted.

Comment: @LutzHorn Ok, maybe not insults, but criticism. Close enough.

Comment: You're not banned from SO, you've been temporarily banned from chat. That's what happens when your comments are flagged and they're deleted. [Don't overreact to it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293213/why-we-dont-keep-public-records-of-suspensions/293335#293335)

Comment: Merriam Webster defines "dumb" as lacking intelligence, showing a lack of intelligence, or requiring no intelligence. The first two are hard to defend as not going against the owner of the "dumb" thing. The final would be more clearly represented by saying "basic"... or just omitting the reference as I can't see any reason why that would be necessary.

Comment: "Is it unwelcoming to call someone's question dumb?" is a dumb question.

Comment: you get it @Will ... my question is dumb. Anyway, I did spoke with few people (that share community's opinion) about situation and I can't see logic behind ... you get offended because one random guy said to other random guy that question is stupid ... anyway, point of comment was `not to insult her` (as I said, its not her that's dumb, it's the question, in my mind there is huge diff) and as she is insulted I do apologize to her and i do wish her best in future

Comment: Forget for a minute if the offense was meant or not, if it was merited or not, or how it was perceived. What did you achieve by telling this other random guy that question was stupid? How does that help anyone on this site? You, the other guy, the OP, or future visitors?

Comment: It is still a good thing to give advice about how to better ask a question, its all about increasing the chance of success. So yeah... just like a question can be stupid, so can the way help is offered be stupid. It really doesn't have to be that hard: on Stack Overflow you do not use overbearing language. No rudeness, no crassness, no tongue-in-cheekiness, no ball breaking, no nothing. Just dull, neutral interactions. Much like when you meet new colleagues for the first time. "Hi, I'm X and I'm from Y", followed by a stiff handshake.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank A person is insulted when you disparage the thing they make. If you are an artist and I call your art stupid or crappy, that's not directly insulting you, but it is insulting your skill and effort as an artist. Same with asking a question, and why the maxim "there is no such thing as a stupid question" exists in such popularity today.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Stating that a question is "stupid as hell" is rude. And above that it is completely unnecessary and useless. It does not help OP to improve their question and does not contain any valuable information for other people trying to answer the question.

In general: Don't write anything in a comment/chat-post that doesn't help to improve the question. Suggestions on how to modify a question are good, but calling a question dumb isn't.

Since you brought the topic up yourself, parts of your last chatroom post are also rude, condescending and borderline sexist. Saying "poor little lady :D" to another developer who complains that you've been rude to them is absolutely not nice and I highly doubt anyone would ever say something like this in a real conversation.

I'm honestly a bit surprised that such sayings didn't get you chat-banned.

Comment: He did get as short chat-ban now.