# How do I get more context on flagged chat messages?

Tags: discussion, chat, spam, offensive-flag

I just saw the feature to vote to remove chat messages that were flagged as offensive or spam. The first one I am presented with is:

> poor little lady :D

This is ***most probably*** a sexist comment. However, without context, it's impossible to say that for sure. For example, it could be part of a conversation where chat users are testing a web service, and are comparing the captcha phrases.

How can I review the context of the message, before voting?

Comment: Where can this feature be seen?

Comment: @LutzHorn It just appeared in the bottom left of the chat screen. I don't see it now so I can't screenshot it - presumably the review queue is clear.

Comment: I normally click the user link and then the tab recent to see the recent messages. From there I click in the offending message which brings me in context in the chat transcript. But make it quick. Those flags normally don't stay up long.

Comment: Ah. Yeah I tried something like that but it didn't find the message. Most likely deleted already. Would be good if there was a way to jump directly to the message from the notification.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371126/was-i-not-welcoming-enough

Comment: @Script47 Oh wow. The flag I had to review was from that exact same user!

Comment: Seems like some peoples really have a problem with the "be nice" thing. I mean it's pretty straight-forward that mocking her this way is child-ish aswell as really rude. Gosh. As for OP, i got peoples in my office complaining about this issue: it's there but not easy enough to access. Migth be a feature-request ?

Comment: @LutzHorn It's a 10k tool. [Meta.SE on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65827/how-can-i-see-flags-from-the-chat)

Comment: a sexist comment using a gendered word does not make. they're words. they're not inherently sexist, no. "Poor little boy|lady" is condescending, sure. Stop bringing the inquisition and tabooing words, please.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Yes of course, there are plenty of situations where this particular phrase could be just fine - it's just three words and a smiley! However, somebody bothered to flag the message which means it was offensive to at least one person. Maybe that person was just being oversensitive but it's impossible to tell from the information shown. That's why I'm asking about how to see more context, rather than judge it purely on its surface words.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371126/was-i-not-welcoming-enough for details about this specific comment. The comment was part of a larger not very nice situation and I flagged both involved comments. I agree with the proposal. Without the context the comment can be a funny conversation between two friends or an offensive one as in this particular case.

Answer (score 33):

This is always confusing because, as I [noted elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366798/2370483) you're never given context on the flag window

[image: Chat flag window]

There's a couple of paths here

1. Click the **show all** link (takes you to [this page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/admin/flagged?show=all)) where you can view them as normal chat messages. Mouse over them, click the inverted triangle, and you can get the permalink there (this example is from general chat, but the flagged window works the same)

   [image]
2. Click the room name in the flag window. It's not obvious, but it will open the chat transcript to that message.

Comment: @rene I just clicked on the recent flags and it took me to the transcript. [Example](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43272721#43272721) (the offensive post was deleted by flags but the move event remains)

Comment: In the initial display of the flags (i.e. the popup with "valid", "invalid", and "no sure"), you can also click on the room name, "JavaScript" in this case, which is a permalink to the post. It will open up the transcript view. That's not the actual chat room, so parent/child association isn't highlighted (i.e. replied-to links), but it does give more context.

Comment: @Makyen Transcripts don't include reply highlighting on hover, but if you click the reply arrow at the beginning of a chat reply it will refresh the transcript with the target message highlighted. So it does include reply highlighting on click, after a fashion (and only one reply at a time, not all associated messages in a reply-conversation).

Comment: @TylerH, After a fashion. :-) But, yeah, that's a fairly frustrating way to deal with it. I've been tempted to write a userscript to add the parent/child highlighting on the transcript page, but haven't gotten around to it.

Comment: I do what @Makyen says and click on the room name so I can see the flagged message in the transcript. I normally _don't_ want to visit the room itself, I just want a quick peek to get the context. But if things look like they're out of control (as happened yesterday in a certain room which shall remain nameless ;) ), then I'll visit the room briefly.

Comment: Could you edit this so that you're not putting 2 users on blast please?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Done, although the link to the previous thread is there